# Java Class Constructor Error

Tags: java, user-interface

I am building my own GUI that will display a list of Friend's objects in list form. The first problem I ran into is that when I run the code without a constructor, everything works fine. But when I create a constructor for my GUI class, the error message displayed:

```
load: GUIapp.class is not public or has no public constructor.
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class sun.applet.AppletPanel can not access a member of             class GUIapp with modifiers ""
at sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Reflection.java:65)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:349)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
at sun.applet.AppletPanel.createApplet(AppletPanel.java:807)
at sun.applet.AppletPanel.runLoader(AppletPanel.java:714)
at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(AppletPanel.java:368)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

My Code:

```
public class GUIapp extends JApplet{

/*
 * Attributes
 */

//** Friends Objects**//
private FriendsGroup a;
private ArrayList<friends> friendList;

//** PANEL **//
private JPanel outerPanel;

//** Button **//
private JButton button1;


/*
 * Constructor for Getting all the friends set up
 */

private GUIapp(){
    a = null;  //initialize variable

    try {
        a = new FriendsGroup("friends.txt"); //import friend list
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Fail Import.");
    }

    friendList = a.getFriendsGroup(); //return an arrayList of Friends Object
}


/*
 * Create Stuff
 */
public void createStuff() {
    outerPanel = new JPanel(); //create outer panel
    button1 = new JButton("Click Me");
    outerPanel.add(button1,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}


/*
 * Initialize Stuff
 * 
 */
public void init(){
    createStuff(); //initialize create stuff

    this.add (outerPanel); 
}
}
```

In the Above Code, if you take out the constructor, it seems to work perfectly. My Question is, what is wrong with the code? Why can't I seem to create a constructor to load in data first?

My Second Question is how would I go about create a panel whereby it displays a list of friends names? Theses names are imported and stored in the arraylist of friends Object called friendList stored in the constructor.

Thanks,

Comment: There is nothing wrong to create a constructor, unless it's not private, and the only constructor in the class.

Comment: This might be helpful: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/ctorTrouble.html

Comment: Re: your edit: please don't move the goalposts with edits. The NullPointerException is a new problem that should go into a new SO question and that you should try to work out first. Don't expect people to walk you through your whole program once you have someone's attention.

Comment: what does getFriendsGroup() do?

Comment: Apologies, I wont do that again. getriendsGroup() is a method of FriendsGroup that returns an ArrayList(). The FriendsGroup class is used to parse a text file that and create Friends object along the way.

Comment: Please ask another question if you want to ask another scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you are defining a constructor by yourself
compiler will not create the default constructor
since your defined constructor is private
you will not have a public constructor

so simply create a public constructor

```
public GUIapp(){
    // your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

because you define constructor `private` change it to;

```
public GUIapp(){
    a = null;  //initialize variable

    try {
        a = new FriendsGroup("friends.txt"); //import friend list
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Fail Import.");
    }

    friendList = a.getFriendsGroup(); //return an arrayList of Friends Object
}
```

Comment: I just made an edit to the question. When I declare it public, i get a whole new error

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this: `private GUIapp(){`. That means that your constructor is available only to that class. Usually constructors are `public`, although there do exist exceptions, example of which could be the [Singleton Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

Removing the constructor works because each class, by default has a parameterless constructor. Take a look at [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) tutorial for more information on access modifiers.

Alternatively, you could have a method like so in your `GUIapp` class:

`public static GUIapp getInstance() { return new GUIapp(); }`

and you call that from your main class, but I think that in this case, changing your constructor from `private` to `public` should be enough.

Regarding your second question, [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) tutorial should be of help.

Answer (score 0):

You ened to change syour constructor to public and debug into:

```
a.getFriendsGroup();
```

Its not clear what this methode does, and i assume for some reason (maby the list from the file is empt) the methode tries to access a non assigned object which causes null reference exception, try to debug into the methode to see where this happends or post the code of the methode.